# PayPal IPN Always Returns "INVALID"

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

### My problem

I set up an IPN listener in PHP, but it always returns `INAVLID` when testing with PayPal's IPN Simulator.

I know that this is a frequently asked question, but I have spent an entire weekend reading 50+ similar questions and trying out their solutions, but not a single one of them worked for me.

Note: I have to use fsock, my server does not support cURL.

### What I tried

- Ensured that my server is sending the request to `www.sandbox.paypal.com` and not `www.paypal.com`.
- Ensured that my server uses SSL and port 443.
- Ensured that the `Host` header is not missing.
- Ensured that my response is equal to PayPal's request, prefixed with `cmd=_notify-validate&`.
- Ensured that my server is parsing the `VERIFIED` / `INVALID` response correctly (PayPal's new system sends `7\r\nINVALID\r\n0` instead of just `INVALID`).

### My code

#### IPN listener class

```
<?php
/**
 *  PayPal IPN Listener
 *
 *  A class to listen for and handle Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) from
 *  the PayPal server.
 *
 *  Forked from the great Quixotix PayPal IPN script. This fork plans to
 *  fix the current issues with the original repo, as well as update the code
 *  for use according to PayPal's documentation, and today's standards.
 *
 *  @package    PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @link       https://github.com/WadeShuler/PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @forked     https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
 *  @author     Wade Shuler
 *  @copyright  Copyright (c) 2015, Wade Shuler
 *  @license    http://choosealicense.com/licenses/gpl-2.0/
 *  @version    2.5.2
 */
class IpnListener
{
    /**
     *  If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back
     *  to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_curl = true;
    /**
     *  If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any
     *  "Location: ..." headers in the response.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $follow_location = false;
    /**
     *  If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
     *  post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
     *
     *  @var boolean
     */
    public $use_sandbox = false;
    /**
     *  The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
     *  before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
     *
     *  @var int
     */
    public $timeout = 30;
    /**
     * If true, enable SSL certification validation when using cURL
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    public $verify_ssl = true;
    private $_errors = array();
    private $post_data;
    private $rawPostData;               // raw data from php://input
    private $post_uri = '';
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';
    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';
    /**
     *  Post Back Using cURL
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @todo add URL param so function is more dynamic
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data)
    {
        $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $this->post_uri = $uri;
        $ch = curl_init();
        if ($this->verify_ssl) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/cert/api_cert_chain.crt');
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        return $this->response;
    }
    /**
     *  Post Back Using fsockopen()
     *
     *  Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
     *  the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
     *  exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
     *  and post_uri properties on success.
     *
     *  @todo add URL param so function is more dynamic
     *
     *  @param  string  The post data as a URL encoded string
     */
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data)
    {
        $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
        $port = '443';
        $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);
        if (!$fp) {
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");
        while(!feof($fp)) {
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024);
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        return $this->response;
    }
    private function getPaypalHost()
    {
        return ($this->use_sandbox) ? self::SANDBOX_HOST : self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }
    public function getErrors()
    {
        return $this->_errors;
    }
    private function addError($error)
    {
        $this->_errors[] .= $error;
    }
    public function getPostData()
    {
        return $this->post_data;
    }
    public function getRawPostData()
    {
        return $this->rawPostData;
    }
    /**
     *  Get POST URI
     *
     *  Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
     *  be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
     *  would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getPostUri()
    {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }
    /**
     *  Get Response
     *
     *  Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
     *  HTTP headers.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponse()
    {
        return $this->response;
    }
    /**
     *  Get Response Status
     *
     *  Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
     *  if the post back was successful.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getResponseStatus()
    {
        return $this->response_status;
    }
    /**
     *  Get Text Report
     *
     *  Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
     *  useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
     *  this method in your own class to customize the report.
     *
     *  @return string
     */
    public function getTextReport()
    {
        $r = '';
        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) {
            $r .= " (curl)\n";
        } else {
            $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";
        }
        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";
        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";
        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";
        return $r;
    }
    /**
     *  Process IPN
     *
     *  Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
     *  method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
     *  back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and
     *  throws an exception if there is an error.
     *
     *  @param array
     *
     *  @return boolean
     */
    public function processIpn($post_data=null)
    {
        try
        {
            $this->requirePostMethod();     // processIpn() should check itself if data is POST
            // Read POST data
            // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
            // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
            if ($post_data === null) {
                $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                $raw_post_data = $post_data;
            }
            $this->rawPostData = $raw_post_data;                            // set raw post data for Class use
            // if post_data is php input stream, make it an array.
            if ( ! is_array($raw_post_data) ) {
                $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
                $this->post_data = $raw_post_array;                             // use post array because it's same as $_POST
            } else {
                $this->post_data = $raw_post_data;                              // use post array because it's same as $_POST
            }
            $myPost = array();
            if (isset($raw_post_array)) {
                foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
                    $keyval = explode('=', $keyval);
                    if (count($keyval) == 2) {
                        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
            $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
            foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
                if (function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc') && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                } else {
                    $value = urlencode($value);
                }
                $req .= "&$key=$value";
            }

            //XXX Debug log
            $file = fopen('lastresponse.log', 'w');
            fwrite($file, $req);
            fclose($file);

            if ($this->use_curl) {
                $res = $this->curlPost($req);
            } else {
                $res = $this->fsockPost($req);
            }
            if (strpos($res, '200') === false) {
                throw new Exception("Invalid response status: " . $res);
            }
            // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
            $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
            $res = trim(end($tokens));
            if (strpos ($res, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
                return true;
            } else if (strpos ($res, "INVALID") !== false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal: " . $res);
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->addError($e->getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
    /**
     *  Require Post Method
     *
     *  Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
     *  method was not POST.
     */
    public function requirePostMethod()
    {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
```

#### Actual IPN listener

```
<?php

ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "php-error.log");

$file = fopen('lastrequest.log', 'w');
fwrite($file, file_get_contents('php://input'));
fclose($file);

require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_includes/ipnlistener.php';

$listener = new IpnListener();
$listener->use_sandbox = true;
$listener->use_curl = false;
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

if ($verified = $listener->processIpn())
{
    // Valid IPN
    /*
        1. Check that $_POST['payment_status'] is "Completed"
        2. Check that $_POST['txn_id'] has not been previously processed
        3. Check that $_POST['receiver_email'] is your Primary PayPal email
        4. Check that $_POST['payment_amount'] and $_POST['payment_currency'] are correct
    */
    $transactionRawData = $listener->getRawPostData();      // raw data from PHP input stream
    $transactionData = $listener->getPostData();            // POST data array
    // Feel free to modify path and filename. Make SURE THE DIRECTORY IS WRITEABLE!
    // For security reasons, you should use a path above/outside of your webroot
    file_put_contents('ipn_success.log', print_r($transactionData, true) . PHP_EOL, LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
} else {
    // Invalid IPN
    $errors = $listener->getErrors();
    // Feel free to modify path and filename. Make SURE THE DIRECTORY IS WRITEABLE!
    // For security reasons, you should use a path above/outside of your webroot
    file_put_contents('ipn_errors.log', print_r($errors, true) . PHP_EOL, LOCK_EX | FILE_APPEND);
}

file_put_contents("verified.log", $verified ? "VERIFIED" : "INVALID");
```

### My logs

#### PayPal's request

```
payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sun%20Dec%2006%202015%2020%3A05%3A21%20GMT%2B0100%20%28Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische%20Zeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John%20Smith&address_country=United%20States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San%20Jose&address_street=123%20any%20street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=936522821&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A61b6KnaHJWRwuKxRGWvWo2Bos20
```

#### My server's response

```
cmd=_notify-validate&payment_type=instant&payment_date=Sun+Dec+06+2015+20%3A05%3A21+GMT%2B0100+%28Mitteleurop%C3%A4ische+Zeit%29&payment_status=Completed&address_status=confirmed&payer_status=verified&first_name=John&last_name=Smith&payer_email=buyer%40paypalsandbox.com&payer_id=TESTBUYERID01&address_name=John+Smith&address_country=United+States&address_country_code=US&address_zip=95131&address_state=CA&address_city=San+Jose&address_street=123+any+street&business=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_email=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&receiver_id=seller%40paypalsandbox.com&residence_country=US&item_name1=something&item_number1=AK-1234&tax=2.02&mc_currency=USD&mc_fee=0.44&mc_gross=12.34&mc_gross1=12.34&mc_handling=2.06&mc_handling1=1.67&mc_shipping=3.02&mc_shipping1=1.02&txn_type=cart&txn_id=936522821&notify_version=2.1&custom=xyz123&invoice=abc1234&test_ipn=1&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A61b6KnaHJWRwuKxRGWvWo2Bos20
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the same issue and cant find the solution.

Comment: @kokoseq Sadly not, even the PayPal support couldn't find the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spent almost 2 days on this issue and thought I would share with people what have worked for me hopefully It can help a few others who faced the same issue.

### Problem

PayPal IPN simulator gives INVALID IPN response always.

### Solution

When simulating change the `payment_date` in simulator fields to `NULL` and everything should start working if your setup is correct.

Comment: Well, good to know. I don't have the server anymore (so I can't test if this actually works) and I gave up on the whole PayPal thing long ago (this question is 9 months old), but I'm just going to assume that this would have fixed it and mark your answer as the solution. Hopefully someone with the same issue will benefit from it.

Comment: The solution to removing date doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

IPN Simulator uses Sandbox environment, but your IPN Listener class is setting to `public $use_sandbox = false;`, that means you are in Live environment, which could be the cause of the issue of your response always getting `INVALID`.

Comment: The class has it set to `false` by default, but my actual IPN listener (see second code block) calls `$listener->use_sandbox = true;` right after creating the listener.

Comment: Any reason why you are splitting up the code to class and actual listener?

Can you try this piece of code, see if it is working for you?

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php

Comment: I sadly cannot use this particular piece of code, as it uses cURL and my server only supports fsock. I'm using this class because it seems to be the most up-to-date IPN listener implementation out there and because it doesn't require cURL.